# Using JavaScript session in CakePHP 2

Tags: javascript, php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i'm trying to use Session created in javascript in controller in CakePHP 2. I create session like this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('language', document.querySelector('select#langSelect').options[document.querySelector('select#langSelect').selectedIndex].value);
document.querySelector('select#langSelect').addEventListener('change', function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('language', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
    window.location.reload();
});
```

And in javascript console it displays fine, but when i try to display it in CakePHP controller like this:

```
debug($this->Session->read('language'));
```

It shows that it's null. And i try to create the session in main javascript file as well as in layout, but none of it worked. And i cannot create session in controller because i need to get select value.
So could you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Those are two different technologies that do not interact with each other. Why are you trying to connect them? Are you sure that you actually need to use web storage in the first place?

Comment: Ok, i got it working, i just executed AJAX call to php function that sets the session.